# snakemake doesn't execute the right rules

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm using snakemake `7.25.0`. Sometimes, some of my rules are **not** re-executed after a parameter change. Sometimes it detects a parameter change, and sometimes it doesn't. More generally, I'm experiencing a lot of strange behavior of snakemake, and it's hard to understand when it decides to execute a rule or not.

I was able to reproduce **two** weird behaviors on this minimal example:

```
rule all:
    input:
        "res.txt"

checkpoint save_number_files:
    output:
        "n.txt",
    params:
        x = 2,
        t = 3,
    shell:
        "echo {params.x} > {output}"

rule create_file:
    input:
        "n.txt",
    output:
        "out/{index}.txt"
    shell:
        "touch {output}"

def get_n(wilcards):
    with checkpoints.save_number_files.get(**wilcards).output[0].open() as f:
        return [f"out/{i}.txt" for i in range(int(f.read()))]

rule aggregate:
    input:
        get_n
    output:
        "res.txt"
    shell:
        """touch {output}"""
```

Step to reproduce the strange behaviors:

1. Run the pipeline once (`snakemake -c1`). It should be fine.
2. Change the value of `t`, for instance `t = 4` and re-execute the pipeline. It executes `save_number_files`, but doesn't re-execute `create_file`, even though its input changed.
3. Re-execute the pipeline (without any change!). It now re-runs the rule `all` instead of saying `Nothing to be done`. This is not critical since it's actually doing nothing, but I'm surprise that it doesn't say `Nothing to be done` even though we didn't changed anything...

Comment: It looks **sort of**(?) like [this bug](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/2175) but you are saying it happens with only one checkpoint. And you aren't involving `--touch`. It also looks sort of like [this report](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1628), too. It also [looks ALOT like it is related to this FIXED bug](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1818#issuecomment-1225047474). It is marked as fixed as of 7.16.0+. Maybe there was a regression again?

Comment: Thanks @Wayne, I'll have a look to these issues, try different versions of snakemake (old ones and newer ones), and if nothing works I'll open an issue!